# How to loop within Firebase transaction?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have emotes array which as Smiley1, Smiley2, Smiley3.

using bellow cloud function and transaction im trying to increment value of each by 100. but looping is not working .

after running, in my user collection it setting emoji  = 300.

can anybody tell where im going wrong.

if i can create array field and update each Smiley count will also be better help

**like emojis[Smiley1: 100, Smiley2: 100, Smiley3: 100]**

```
async function updateEmotesCount(userID, emotes) {
    const userRef: DocumentReference = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userID}`);
    return admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction: Transaction) => {
        emotes.forEach((emoji) => {
            transaction.update(userRef, {
                emoji: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(100),
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you please modify your question with formatting your code? Please read the help on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you don't need to use a Transaction if you only want to increment a field: using `FieldValue.increment(100)` is sufficient, see this [blog article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html).

So you could do as follows:

```
  async function updateEmotesCount(userID, emotes) {
    const userRef: DocumentReference = admin
      .firestore()
      .doc(`users/${userID}`);
      
    const updateObj = {};
    emotes.forEach(emoji => {
        updateObj[emoji] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(100)
    });  
      
    return userRef.update(updateObj);
   }

   const emotes =  ["Smiley1", "Smiley2", "Smiley3"]
   const userID = ...
   await updateEmotesCount(userID, emotes);
```

---

I let you refining this code with an Array like:

```
   const emotes =  [
       {fieldName: "Smiley1", value: 100},
       {fieldName: "Smiley2", value: 200},
       {fieldName: "Smiley3", value: 300}
    ]
```

Comment: @ Renaud Tarnec, currently it will store all 3 Smileys separately. what if i want to create (or update if already exist) a field called  "emotes" and update smiley data within that field everytime.

Comment: Can you add some more details at the bottom of your question: what is the type of this field emotes? An Array? A map?

Comment: it will be a map, emotes{"Smiley1": 100, "Smiley2": 300, "Smiley3": 500,  }  , instead of separate Smiley1, Smiley2, in user/id collection, we want all smiley's count in a single field, so that we can access all smileys count using single field "emotes"

Comment: If it's a map, just use the dot notation `emotes.Smiley1 = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(100)` or the square brackets notation `emotes["Smiley1"] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(100)`.

Comment: or in a new collection with users/id/emotes will also be better i guess, what you suggest, in future my app gonna have 50+ smileys